# Vacuum capillary to sample pressure at 1 atm

Tags: pressure, vacuum, capillary-action

I've been trying to design a system to measure pressure at 1 atm using an RGA (Residual Gas Analyzer) from a vacuum. However, this is higher pressure than the RGA is used to (it likes to measure at about 9.87*10^-10 atm, or about 10^-6 mbar). I read that in order to sample the gas at such high pressure, I should use a capillary as per this article: https://www.thinksrs.com/downloads/pdfs/applicationnotes/High_Pres_Sampling.pdf.
However, the article does not state what size capillary I should use. I have been unable to find any guidance on this on the web, and was wondering if anyone knew what size capillary I should use to sample gas at 1 atm. Apologies if this question is unclear, I'm pretty new to this research.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Measure pressure or measure relative partial pressures? Call an application engineer at your RGA supplier.

Comment: Discussion topics should include calibrated leak valves, channels, and/or orifices.